# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, web-applications

Any suggestions to resolve this issue, exception details as below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
    at com.fgn.odf.model.odfParserM.loadOdfDocument(odfParserM.java:34)
    at com.fgn.odf.OdfConverterApplication.main(OdfConverterApplication.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 2 more
```

This happens when it reach here (code mentioned below) - and this class is from a library added to `pom.xml`(maven dependencies)

```java
OdfPackage pkg = OdfPackage.loadPackage(documentPath);
```

Anybody please suggests me what could be wrong ??

Comment: do you see org.apache.xerces.jaxp dependency downloaded?

Comment: No, i checked that dependency is not in effective pom.xml or in maven dependencies ?  should i install it separately ?

Comment: not separately, maybe you can add it to dependencies

Comment: Thank you very much :) the issue solved  added as you said, it is been a long time in java environment : <dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: glad it helped, please accept answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add maven dependency for org.apache.xerces.jaxp

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>xerces</groupId> 
 <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
 <version>2.4.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```